# replace multiple consecutive hyphens with one

Tags: javascript, regex

Is this possible in Javascript?

I have this from Java, but can not be used in Javascript.

```
s/-{2,}/-/g
```

Is there another way that works?

Comment: That regular expression will work *just as well* in JavaScript as it works in Java. (You may want to try "javascript regex replace/tutorial" for the methods that accept regular expressions.)

Answer (score 23):

Yes it is. You can use the same regex with the Javascript [`replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/t0kbytzc%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) method.

```
s.replace(find, replacement)
// where 's' is your string object
```

Example:

```
var r = 'foo--bar---baz'.replace(/-{2,}/g, '-');
console.log(r); // "foo-bar-baz"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can just do this:

```
var newStr = "hi--this is----good".replace(/-+/g,'-'); // hi-this is-good
```

`-+` matches more than 1 `-` and replaces them with a single `-`

Your regex is also valid. Except you cannot use `s` modifier.

Answer (score -3):

```
query.trim().replace(/\s\s+/g, '-').replace(/[\s.;,?%]/, '-')
```